# Cordova splashscreen not being displayed on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm brand new to Cordova and am trying to get the splash screen working on Android. I've followed a few tutorials to the letter and have reviewed the questions here on SO but it's not working yet.

I'm using the 'Cordova CLI' approach - here is my /config.xml:

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>

    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />       
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />    

    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">

        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-logo.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>     

        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />      
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

I know I should have different image sizes for each density but this is a test project so please ignore that.

I've added the cordova-plugin-splashscreen to my project.

```
  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

The splashscreen is still not being displayed - instead a blackscreen turns up when the app runs on the emulator. After a couple of seconds, the blackscreen goes away and the default 'device-ready' Cordova screen appears.

I've done everything suggested in other places - can you guys spot what's wrong?

FYI I was looking at the /plataforms directory and it seems things are correctly set.

The snippet below is from /platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:

```
<splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
<icon density="ldpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
<icon density="mdpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
<icon density="hdpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
<icon density="xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/icon.png" />
```

There are screen.png files under every directory listed above - so it seems Cordova is doing its work correctly.

---

Main activity:

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post main activity code ?

Comment: Errr.... maybe. Where can I find it? :) I thought the activity stuff was Android-specific and as I'm using Cordova CLI I wasn't supposed to meddle with it.

Comment: in your android project src folder main activity java file will be their.

Comment: your main activity looking perfect but have you added splash screen plugins properly ?

Comment: Which plugin version are you using? The version can be seen in `cordova plugins` output. Try to `cordova plugin rm splashscreen && cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen` as @jaydroider suggested. Alternatively try to add `<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="500"/>` to `config.xml`.

Comment: 3.1.0 - I appreciate that you are willing to help me but I have now given up on using Cordova and have decided to go with Ionic instead. Doing exactly the same thing on Ionic has worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've struggled with this issue for quite some time too, and found out that the problem is in the values for `SplashScreenDelay` and `FadeSplashScreenDuration`.

If you look at [SplashScreen.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java), you'll find that the `showSplashScreen` function executes the following:

```
final int fadeSplashScreenDuration = getFadeDuration();
final int effectiveSplashDuration = Math.max(0, splashscreenTime - fadeSplashScreenDuration);
```

In your config, you've set the `SplashScreenDelay` to be 2000 ms.

`getFadeDuration` looks for the `FadeSplashScreenDuration` element and when not found (in this case) falls back to the default `DEFAULT_SPLASHSCREEN_DURATION`, which is 3000 ms, resulting in a negative value for the `effectiveSplashDuration`. Apparently this will lead to no splashscreen being displayed.

So the solutions are

- add a `FadeSplashScreenDuration` element to the configuration with the value set to 0. (or any number *smaller* than 2000)
- Increase the value of `SplashScreenDelay` to 4000 (or any number *larger* than 3000)

Comment: What a finding! It looks to me like a poor decision - they should reckon the value for FadeSplashScreenDuration (say 20% of splashscreenTime for instance) instead of setting a default value of 3K. I have now given up on Cordova and am working with Ionic - but I set the duration to 10K in my old project and it worked - so I'm accepting your answer as correct. Thank you so much for this :)

Comment: What the hell... thank you so much! This took me half a day. Works perfect now!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this in your cofig.xml file.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

 <feature name="SplashScreen" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param
        name="onload"
        value="true" />
</feature>
```

this might solve your problem.

Comment: negetive voters please specify what;s wrong with this answer.

Comment: thanks for it. These elements are present in the /platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml - they were automatically added by Cordova. It's still not working :(

Comment: but your posted config.xml doesn't contains that so you can also add that manually.

Comment: Because that's my config.xml under the root directory. The config.xml for Android generated by Cordova does contain those elements.

Comment: uninstall your plugin once with command cordova remove and try to install with git url cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git